# How to configure app.yaml on GAE with PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm getting stuck in configuring app.yaml on GAE in order to redirect in PHP code. I'd like to redirect to another HTML page called thanks.html in thanks/thanks.html directory after pushing submit button in index.php. However, it redirects to index.php from index.php With the current settings. I think PHP code don't detect my thanks.html. So I'd like to ask you what point is wrong on my app.yaml and should I use dispatch.yaml ?? Thank you so much . Except redirecting, other functions are working fine.

my directory structure is
[image]

```
index.php(only the part of redirect to thanks.html)

header("Location: ./thanks/thanks.html");
exit();
```

```
app.yaml

runtime: php72
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: .*
  script: auto
  http_headers:

- url: /thanks
  static_dir: /thanks

env_variables:
        SENDGRID_API_KEY: "*********"
        DEVELOPER_EMAIL: "********"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to deploy a [front controller](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime#app_startup) to handle all request routing in App Engine. Deploy with the codes below:

**index.php**:

```
<?php
header("Location: ./thanks/thanks.html");
exit();
switch (@parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path']) {
    case '/':
        require 'index.php';
        break;
    case 'thanks/thanks.html':
        require 'thanks.html';
        break;
    default:
        http_response_code(404);
        exit('Not Found');
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried to add your code and it redirected to same page , index.php.

Comment: What do you mean? It should always redirect to `thanks.html`.

Comment: sorry . I fount typo on my code . let me check again.

Comment: If you encountered for `thanks.html` not found, go to your `app.yaml` in `- url: /thanks` change the `static_dir` value from `/thanks` to `thanks` only.

Comment: Let me know if you have other concern or error about this issue.

Comment: thank you for your advice . I solved this problem.

Comment: sorry.I'm newbe in here . I accepted your answer but I'm mot sure does it means "vote" as you said . If there is still something I have to do, please let me know .