# Configuring app.yaml on GAE in order to redirect to html file from PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I got stuck in configuring app.yaml on GAE again. I have already solved similar problem as like last post [Last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66791352/how-to-configure-app-yaml-on-gae-with-php/66793133?noredirect=1#comment118087521_66793133) . now I need to change the directory of thanks.html and I changed code and deployed again but it keeps showing index.php after redirect with the URL .domain/thanks.html ←my app seems to detect redirect url to thanks.html that I set on my code but shows index.php. I have followed GCP documentation but it was not deployed as I expected. If there is any mistake in my code , anyone teach me how to revise ?? Thank you so much .

my directory is below .
[image]

```
index.php(the only part of redirect to thanks.html)
            header("Location: thanks.html");
            exit();
            switch (@parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path']) {
                 case '/':
                      require 'index.php';
                      break;
                 case './thanks.html':
                      require 'thanks.html';
                      break;
                 default:
                        http_response_code(404);
                        exit('Not Found');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                syslog(LOG_ERR, 'Exception: '. $e->getMessage());
        }
```

```
runtime: php72
entrypoint: serve index.php
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: .*
  script: auto

- url: /
  static_files: thanks.html
  upload: thanks.html

env_variables:
        SENDGRID_API_KEY: "*****"
        DEVELOPER_EMAIL: "*****"
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with code below but I had already tried same code in several times but this time it worked fine . I'm always really confused with deploying in GAE.

```
imndex.php

try {
                $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
                header("Location: ./thanks.html");
                exit();
                switch (@parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path']) {
                    case '/':
                        require 'index.php';
                        break;
                    case './thanks.html':;
                        require './thanks.html';
                        break;
                    default:
                        http_response_code(404);
                        exit('Not Found');
                }
            }
```

```
app.yaml

- url: /thanks.html
  static_files: thanks.html
  upload: thanks.html
```